# Apache 2.4 + FPM + Wordpress Multisite: URL Rewrite not working in admin

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just moved a Wordpress multi-site from a Apache 2.4 Prefork + mod_php to a new server with Apache 2.4 Event + php-fpm.

The site is working well on the frontend and it is a lot faster then before due to the CGI, but... the Wordpress administration panel is working just for the main site (and network administration).
The admin area for the second site is no more working, but the frontend is working great.

Examples

- http://www.example.com/en/wp-admin/ => works
- http://www.example.com/en/wp-admin/post-new.php => goes on error 404

I tried to debug the rewrites, but the unique log I have (also using Debug Level 8) is

```
[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 13700:tid 140381047965440] [client X.X.X.X:54354] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n', referer: http://www.example.com/en/wp-admin/
```

Follwing my configurations.
Any help appreciated. Thank you.

**Virtual Host**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
DocumentRoot "/srv/www/example.com/public_html"
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/srv/www/example.com/public_html/$1
</IfModule>
<Directory "/srv/www/example.com/public_html">
AllowOverride all
Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog /srv/www/example.com/logs/error_log
TransferLog /srv/www/example.com/logs/access_log
</VirtualHost>
```

**.htaccess**

```
<Files "xmlrpc.php">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded ﬁles
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?ﬁles/(.+) wp-includes/ms-ﬁles.php?ﬁle=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(admin|content|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+]/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you found the solution. Just like to share our solution to this issue.

We've just added the lines below to the apache config. This will do the forwarding to FPM for all items in the regex.

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(admin|activate|blog-header|comments-post|config|cron|links-opml|load|login|mail|settings|signup|trackback)\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/$2
```

Comment: I modified it a little bit: `ProxyPassMatch "^/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+\/)?((wp-(admin|activate|blog-header|comments-post|config|cron|links-opml|load|login|mail|settings|signup|trackback))\/.*.php(\/.*)?)" "fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/phoenix/$2" enablereuse=on`

Answer (score 3):

I add a different solution because [@parpar's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39737723/3495761), although it is working for me, it continues to throw `proxy_fcgi` errors:

```
[proxy_fcgi:error] Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
```

The solution consists in removing the ProxyPassMatch way to call PHP FPM and including a handler to manage PHP calls into the `Directory` environment:

```
<Directory "/path/to/host/root">
   # rest of configuration...
   <FilesMatch \.php$>
      SetHandler "proxy:unix:/path/to/socket.sock|fcgi://localhost"
   </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Please correct the typo FileMarch in your example. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

As I moved a WordPress multisite from a local XAMPP installation to a Ubuntu 18.04 server with Apache 2.4.29 and php-fpm I had the exact same issues and thus found this post.

For everyone also struggling with this, I found the following ressources helpful, however they did not work for me out of the box:

- Same issue, different soloution approaches, which however did not work for me out of the box: https://serverfault.com/questions/450628/apache-2-4-php-fpm-proxypassmatch
- Apache Doc on php-fpm with helpful and explained examples and even examples for Wordpress (however nothing  multisite specific):

  - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/httpd/PHP-FPM
  - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/PHPFPMWordpress

Instead of using `ProxyPassMatch` I ended up using the following Apache configuration in the virtual host for the migrated page:

```
...
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
            SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
        </If>
    </FilesMatch>
...
```

With this configuration the Wordpress Mulisite .htaccess is recognized by apache and thus the Rewrite rules for multisite routes are applied. Due to the if statement only existing php files are passed to php-fpm.

So far both main and `/en/` routes resolve correctly for frontend and admin pages.