# Subsite admin page 404 error of WordPress Multisite

Tags: wordpress, multisite

When i try to login in wp-admin its opens perfectly fine but when i try to open dashboard of subsite, its dashboard loads without css and none of the links opens (below screenshot of the error) while the default dashboard working perfectly fine. This setup is working fine on my test server.
Any help and fast response is appreciated.

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwLQt.png)

This is my .htaccess rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/site1/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

wp-config multisite setup

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'demo.site.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/wordpress/site1/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

Comment: Can you please share your htaccess file code here...

Comment: Updated. Please check my .htacess. also check the error screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. 
Problem was in the server. 
It was not working with php-fpm. 
Now fixed this from server and server admin did it.
If anyone found this problem please make sure about php-fpm. 
Also contact with server admin. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your htaccess rule like below.

For anyone following this thread, the error was caused by the last line of code:

```
RewriteRule ./ /index.php [L]
```

And the fix is putting this instead:

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: @Anam after changed above code , It 's working or not?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the error that I changed the proxy to a handler:

Old: with error:

```
ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$" "fcgi://127.0.0.1:9001/var/www/dev" enablereuse=on
```

**New - working:**

```
        <Directory> 
            ...
            <FilesMatch \.php$>
                SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://localhost:9001"
            </FilesMatch>
        </Directory>
```

see original post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47655434/601269